# Getting specific # of characters

Tags: c

I want to get only 2 characters in my program. I tried fgets but I can get it to work. How do you suggest that I implement this? Or is there any alternative?

```
char code[2];
printf("Enter code: \n");
scanf("%s", code);`
```

> I want to limit the number of characters that can be entered to two.

Comment: `fgetc(fp)` (twice) or `fscanf(fp, "%c%c", &c1, &c2)` are two options.

Comment: You want to read from `stdin`? You can limit the number of chars `fgets` reads to 2. You can do the same with `getline`. Another choice is `scanf` with 2 characters in the format string.

Comment: If you have `char code[3];` (note 3, not 2) you can use `scanf("%2s", code);`, but there are caveats: initial white space will be skipped, and if there's one character and then white space, you'll get just one character in the string.  If you simply want two characters, then: `code[0] = getchar(); code[1] = getchar();` is almost OK (except that it will mishandle an early EOF).

Comment: are you looking to ignore white space?

Comment: `scanf("%c%c", &code[0], &code[1]);` - most straightforward way via `scanf`

Answer (score 1):

To read two characters and ignore white space you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   char code[2];
   printf("Enter code:\n");
   if (scanf(" %c %c", &code[0], &code[1]) == 2) {
      printf("successfully read '%c' and '%c'\n", code[0], code[1]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

to not ignore white space use `"%c%c"` as the format.

Answer (score -5):

Try this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
char code;
clrscr();
printf("enter the code\n");
scanf("%2s",code);
printf("%s",code);
getch();
}
```

Comment: 1.  `char code` can store only one byte of data, which is wrong in your case. 2. `printf("%s",code);` will always print (null).